# Set line-height of div through jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are 2 divs: Div1 and Div2.

I have a function that determines Div1's height and sets Div2's height to match it if Div2's height is smaller.

I am trying to make that function also set Div2's lineheight equal to Div1's height if Div2's height is smaller.

This is very tricky to me.

My attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function setDiv2Height(){

        var Div1Height = $('#Div1').height();
        var Div2Height = $('#Div2').height();

        if (Div2Height < Div1Height) {    
            $('#Div2').height($('#Div1').height()); 

            $('#Div2').css("line-height", ($('#Div1').height())));
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tkay/fn18t2jm/ remove the extra `)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra `)` . and `div { line-height: 1.2;}` is same as setting `div { line-height: 1.2em;}`. So you might have to change `number` to `number + 'px'`;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(function setDiv2Height(){

        var Div1Height = $('#Div1').height();
        var Div2Height = $('#Div2').height();

        if (Div2Height < Div1Height) {    
            $('#Div2').height($('#Div1').height()); 

            $('#Div2').css("line-height", ($('#Div1').height()+"px"));
        }

    },2000);

});
```

```css
#Div1{
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:100%;
}

#Div2{
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Div1">1qaz</div>
<div id="Div2">1qaz</div>
```

Comment: I agree! There is a closing bracket too much

Answer (score 2):

I consider you can use the `else` clause

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        function setDiv2Height(){

            var Div1Height = $('#Div1').height();
            var Div2Height = $('#Div2').height();

            if (Div2Height < Div1Height) {    
                $('#Div2').height(Div1Height+'px'); 
                $('#Div2').css("line-height", (Div1Height)+'px');
            }else{
                $('#Div1').height(Div2Height+'px'); 
                $('#Div1').css("line-height", (Div2Height)+'px');                   
            }

        }

    });
```

Comment: you sound to be correct @DennisMartinez , but i consider the above code will help out @ Sherri and he can surely proceed ahead

Comment: `line-height` is unitless propety relative to `font-size`. And because jq `height()` method returns unitless value (integer), this OP's stament isn't reached: `Div2's lineheight equal to Div1's height`. As i understand it, you should then specify unit: `$('#Div2').css("line-height", Div1Height + "px");`

Answer (score 2):

Check out the jQuery's [height](https://api.jquery.com/height/) documentation, and you'll see that the method returns an absolute value, as in unit-less (such as 400, instead of 400px). In the second line of your condition, you want to set the `line-height` value of `#Div2`, but see, line-height is a property that requires a value AND a unit of measure, such as `line-height: 3px`. As your code is basically doing `line-height: xx` (no unit), it shouldn't work. I'd use [css](https://api.jquery.com/css/) instead, which returns the value and the unit. This should work:

```
$('#Div2').css("line-height", $('#Div1').css('height'));
```

Also, you had a little parentheses problem in this very line, so watch out for that.

**EDIT:**

As kindly pointed out by [A. Wolff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff), `line-height` does NOT require a unit along with it. Had I been more careful, I'd have seen [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_line-height). But I still think you should use `css()` instead, even when you first set your variables. That's how I'd do it.

Comment: I think this is correct answer BUT this seems wrong statement: `but see, line-height is a property that requires a value AND a unit of measure`  From DOC: `/* Unitless: use this number
multiplied by the element's font size */`  Which is completly valid  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Syntax

Comment: This answer solved my problem as well as provided very good insight into what was causing the error. Another answer also solved my problem that was submitted at the same time so I chose randomly between the two. I wish stackoverflow allowed for choosing multiple as having solved. Sorry about that, but thank you, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem, stranger! The important thing is you got it working =)

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo in your code, maybe this is causing problems?

instead of

```
$('#Div2').css("line-height", ($('#Div1').height())));
```

use

```
$('#Div2').css("line-height", ($('#Div1').height()));
```